# How do I conditionally show a field in ASP.NET MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am very new to C# and ASP.NET MVC Razor.  I want to show a field in my view if the field is not blank.

#### Code

```
<tr class="hide" id="trPhone2">
            <td class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Now, I want to output that first `<tr>` line if the `model.phone2 is ""` and else output:

```
<tr id="trPhone2">
```

How do I do this using ASP.NET MVC Razor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax might not be perfect, but try this:

```
    @{ 
        var trClass = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.phone2) ? "hide" : ""; 
    }

    <tr class="@trClass" id="trPhone2">
        <td class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone2)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: works like a charm! You can also do it like `@Html.ActionLink(" ", "action", "controller", new { id = id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn_details " + @trClass })`

Answer (score 8):

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.phone2))
{
    <tr class="hide" id="trPhone2">
}
else
{
    <tr id="trPhone2">
}
```

Comment: This looked nice and simple but it was throwing errors in my code.  I think because I was mixing c# in with html.

Comment: @dmikester1, show us your code, I believe the error can be easily fixed

Comment: I ended up using one of the other answers.  Thanks

Comment: I pasted your code right in between my other HTML and it was saying there were two id's with trPhone2 and there was 2 open < tr > blocks.

Comment: @dmikester1, you should have replaced the first line with the snippet above. Otherwise the snippet was inserting one `<tr>` tag and the first line of our code was inserting another one - seems like that was the problem. Anyway, its good to know you have found a solution.

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what I did and was getting those errors

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap this field in if condition

```
@if (Model.phone2=="")
{
    <tr class="hide" id="trPhone2">
}
else
{
    <tr id="trPhone2">
}
            <td class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

alternatively, you can simply skip the entire rendering of field like this

```
@if (Model.phone2!="")
{

    <tr id="trPhone2">
        <td class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone2)
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

Which is a better approach as it removes the field entirely from the dom object so removes any possibility of being edited later.

Answer (score 1):

I would calculate the class name in a code block and output that. Something along the lines of:

```
@{
   var phone2ClassName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.phone2) ? "hide" : string.Empty;
}

<tr class="@phone2ClassName" id="trPhone2">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is very complicated logic then use like this:

```
var trId = "";
if(Model[i].FeeType == (int)FeeTypeEnum.LateFee  
    || Model[i].FeeType == (int)FeeTypeEnum.WaivedFee)
{        
    trId=String.Format("{0}_{1}", @Model[i].ProductId, @Model[i].FeeType);
}
else
{
   trId = @Model[i].ProductId.ToString();
}  


<tr id="@trId" >
```