# Display table rows based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an web app using C# and MVC. One of the page has multiple `<tr>` which will contain information but this information gets updated over time (1 month to 6 month) range. So I only want to show the `<tr>` which include the information. The information is stored in a database, each `<tr>` has it's own column. The approach I've gone with is I read the data and apply `if` conditions in the view.

So something like

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SomePropertyOne))
{
   <tr>
     <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomePropertyOne)</td>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomePropertyOne)</td>
   </tr>
}
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SomePropertyTwo))
{
   <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomePropertyTwo)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomePropertyTwo)</td>
   </tr>
}
...
```

I have to this 8 times. So my question is, is there a better approach than this or am I stuck with using all these `if` statements?

Please let me know if you require any further information

Comment: In your example, are the two rows supposed to relate to different properties? Because they both reference `model.SomeProperty`

Comment: @stuartd Yes, they both relate to different properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814119/how-do-i-conditionally-show-a-field-in-asp-net-mvc-razor

Comment: Create a `DisplayTemplate` (for `@model string`) and put the condition in it - then in the VIew use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeProperty, "yourTemplate")` for each property. And note that tables are for tabular data, not layout

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've never used `DisplayTemplates` before. Is it like partial view?

Comment: Create a partial view in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've gone ahead and created a partial view like you suggest but my if statements throw an error about the property not being available. Would you mind providing an example please if you don't mind

Comment: In the template, the model is `string`, so you replace `Model.SomePropertyOne` with just `Model` (and the helpers become `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've got it working, if the model is `string` then it doesn't work, so I've changed the `DisplayTemplate` to include `@model MyViewModel` and then do `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m)` but I don't know if that's correct :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114734/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `DisplayTemplate` containing the condition. In `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` create a partial view (say) `MyTemplate.cshtml`

```
@model string
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model))
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m)</td>
        <td>@Model</td>
    </tr>
}
```

and then in the view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeProperty, "MyTemplate")
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AnotherProperty, "MyTemplate")
.... //etc
```

The `DisplayFor()` will generate the html based on the template, so if the value of the property is `null` or `string.Empty`, then nothing will be generated for that property.

Side note: You should not be using `<table>` elements for layout (refer [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) and [Why Tables Are Bad (For Layout*) Compared to Semantic HTML + CSS](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html)). Instead, use css to style you layout. For example, change the `DisplayTemplate` to

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m)</div>
    <div class="field-value">@Model</div>
</div>
```

and add the following css

```css
.field {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.field-label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    color: #808080;
}
.field-value {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem via reflection, something like that:

```
@foreach(var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
{
    var value = prop.GetValue(Model);
    if (value != null)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@prop.Name</td>
            <td><input value="@value.ToString()" name="@prop.Name" /></td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

But, at this case, you should avoid to use `@Html` helpers, instead - write corresponding html explicitly.